# Jquery - is not a function Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am using Jquery

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js
```

Then i include my function file,which has this function

```
;(function($){  
    $.fn.UPLOAD_IMAGES= function(options) {
        var defaults = { 
            main_url: mainurl
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        // returns the jQuery object to allow for chainability.  
        return this;  
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then I am calling it on click event like

```
/*Image upload*/
    var options_img = {
    type: '',
    id: $('#id').val(),
    controller: 'listings'
};
$("#file_upload").UPLOAD_IMAGES(options_img);
```

It give me `TypeError`

```
UPLOAD_IMAGES is not a function
```

I do not know what i have missed?

Comment: Are you sure `$` is referring to jQuery?

Comment: Are you sure of the loading order? Your js file that creates the function needs to load before you try to use it

Comment: @PatrickEvans OP said it is called on click but tah'ts still a good point

Comment: Aside from the missing reference to `mainurl` your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/n1pLu0da/. Can you please give us a complete example of your problem.

Comment: @A.Wolff, True. In that case, DOE, are there other jQuery scripts being included? You maybe setting the function on one jQuery instance and then having it overwritten by another. We need a more complete example

Comment: @PatrickEvans: Yes i have included before.@A.Wollf: Can you please explain this?

Comment: @DOE Write your code inside $(document).ready() this should work.

Comment: @Prs: I did it but still not working

Comment: @A.Wolff: How can i convert my function to simple and normal jquery function which will work for all jquery versions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Checkout this demo, everything works as expected

```js
var mainurl = 'someUrl';  // <== define mainurl
jQuery.fn.extend({
  UPLOAD_IMAGES: function(options) {
    alert('UPLOAD_IMAGES called') // <== remove later
    var defaults = {
      main_url: mainurl
    };
    var options = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);
    // returns the jQuery object to allow for chainability.  
    return this;
  }
});

var options_img = {
  type: '',
  id: $('#id').val(),
  controller: 'listings'
};
$("#file_upload")
  .UPLOAD_IMAGES(options_img)
  .addClass('sample'); // <== chain call
```

```css
.sample { /* demo to show chainability*/
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="file_upload">
  chainable UPLOAD_IMAGES
</div>
```

Comment: Whoever down voted, would be nice of you to describe the reason